react native 0.74.2 yarn install error "YN0007: │ com.shiva.test@workspace:. must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed"
react native 0.74.2 yarn install giving following error
"YN0007: │ com.shiva.test@workspace:. must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed"
also yarn lifecycle methods are not calling after yarn install
yarn --version : 3.6.4
react native 0.74.2 yarn install giving following error
"YN0007: │ com.shiva.test@workspace:. must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed"
also yarn lifecycle methods are not calling after yarn install
yarn --version : 3.6.4

You should provide more details about your issue, edit your post using formatting options for better readability and remove duplicated fragment. Also, do not forget to mention the solutions you have tried and why they did not work for you.

how to call lifecycle methods like preinstall, post install, prepare in yarn v3
